# how to start working on xamarin with signalr

Tags: signalr, xamarin

I'm new to both Xamarin and SignalR. While I'm able to easily follow the tutorials for SignalR on Visual Studio, and get a sample chat application working, I'm not able to make it work on Xamarin. I tried to reference the signalr assemblies in Xamarin, but it fails with the following error -

`C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(2,2): Error: Exception while loading assemblies: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load assembly 'System.Security, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral`

But I'm not able to find System.Security to add to references.

Am I doing this right?

I also tried looking for SignalR in Components. But couldn't find it.

Also, I tried to find some tutorials on SignalR in Xamarin that would guide me through this process. But I wasn't able to find any. Can someone point me to some blogs/tutorials that can help me setup SignalR in Xamarin?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you install the beta updates as explained in the documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These steps worked for me:

1. Installed the beta updates on Xamarin
2. Got the dev branch on signalr and built it to include mono support
3. Removed reference to signalr.core assembly (this was the one referencing system.security)

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Xamarin.Forms Net standard 
(https://blog.xamarin.com/building-xamarin-forms-apps-net-standard/), just install nuget '`Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client`' and use all sample code provided by microsoft for NET client (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-net-client) into your shared code.